# Bizarre routing table name resolution issue with openvpn

Tags: domain-name-system, routing, openvpn

I have been having some rather odd issues with my routing table. I am running a Debian Wheezy system, and for a while now, whenever I connect to my home wireless network AND my VPN server, (but not with ethernet), dhcp does not work, and the computer grabs a link local address:

```
$ sudo route -n

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.89.0.5      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.89.0.1      10.89.0.5      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.89.0.5      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
xx.xx.xx.xx    192.168.153.1   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 tun0
192.168.251.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

But than when I run `route` I get this:

```
$ sudo route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.89.0.5      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.89.0.1      10.89.89.5      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.89.0.5      *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
authsrvr.com    192.168.153.1   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 tun0
192.168.153.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

The domain 'authsrvr.com' does not appear to exist. Running a `dig` against the name shows that the name is not associated with any hosts on the net. Running a whois query suggests that the domain is a suspended domain:

```
Domain Name: AUTHSRVR.COM
Registrar: PDR LTD. D/B/A PUBLICDOMAINREGISTRY.COM
Sponsoring Registrar IANA ID: 303
Whois Server: whois.PublicDomainRegistry.com
Referral URL: http://www.PublicDomainRegistry.com
Name Server: NS1.SUSPENDED-DOMAIN.COM
Name Server: NS2.SUSPENDED-DOMAIN.COM
Status: clientDeleteProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientDeleteProhibited
Status: clientHold http://www.icann.org/epp#clientHold
Status: clientTransferProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
Status: clientUpdateProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientUpdateProhibited
Updated Date: 15-jun-2015
Creation Date: 21-apr-2015
Expiration Date: 21-apr-2016
```

So why does my computer think that my VPN server's domain name is 'authsrvr.com' ? Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Is there any authsrvr in any of your configuration files? `grep -Ri authsrvr /etc` can help you.

Comment: Not that grep found. I wonder if its a stale domain name leftover from whoever had this IP address before, as I recently acquired it. But that still would not explain why it is in my computers routing table would it?

Comment: The line `xx.xx.xx.xx    192.168.153.1` shows the IP your computer is resolving to authsrvr.com. That IP makes any sense?

Comment: I believe that line is saying that the default gateway when connected to the vpn is xx.xx.xx. through my LAN gateway, 192.168.153.1, For the sake of example let's say 1.2.3.4 is the vpn servers public IP address. So when connected to the VPN it is routing everything to through the VPN at 1.2.3.4 via the router gw at 192.168.153.1. Correct me if I am wrong.